# Why can we take the collection of all open balls?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces

I have a set theoretic question. I don't understand why the collection of open balls of a metric space is a well-defined set. From my understanding of sets, a set is well-defined in Naive set theory if we can check whether an element is in it or not. But how can we check whether a subset is either an open ball or not? It seems very difficult to check.

Maybe my view of a set is too rigid. Is there a better view of whether a set is well-defined?

Thank you.

Comment: A subset $U$ is an open ball of metric space $X$ if there exists some $y \in X$ and some $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $x \in U \leftrightarrow d (x, y) < \varepsilon$.

Comment: Your understanding isn't quite right: a set is well-defined if we can give a precise formal description of what it means to be an element of the set. It may be that the description is extremely hard or impossible to check given some representation of the set and a candidate element.

Comment: How do we know that a description is "precise formal" but not ambiguous or will cause contradiction? @RobArthan

Comment: @Coco: how can a description lead to a contradiction? There may be no man in my house with red hair but my using that description doesn't lead to a contradiction.

Comment: @RobArthan Em yes I agree most descriptions are fine. But I think the set of all sets is a precise description but leads to a contradiction, and the set of large integers is ambiguous. How to make sure the set I am working on is precise and contradiction free?

Comment: @Coco you are absolutely right about the set of all sets being a no-no.  In axiomatic set theory, we have a second requirement in set construction (requirement 1 in my answer below) which solves this issue by only letting you specify subsets of a parent set.

Answer (score 17):

Naive set theory leads to contradictions such as the barber shop paradox, so if you want to be careful in deciding whether a set is well-defined, you need to step beyond naive set theory into a more formal setting like axiomatic set theory.

In axiomatic set theory there are certain sets (e.g., the empty set) which exist by axiom.  If you want to define your own set, however, by describing its elements, we have an axiom (or more precisely an axiom schema) that tells you how you can do this.

Roughly speaking, you need to do two things to specify a new set $S$ by describing its elements.

1. Pick a larger encompassing set, let's call it $A$, which you intend to satisfy $S\subseteq A$.
2. Create a formal statement $\phi$ in the language of set theory with one free variable such that the elements of your set $S$ are precisely those members $x\in A$  such that $\phi(x)$ is true.  In symbols $$S:=\{x\in A\mid \phi(x)\}\text{.}$$

This is called the [axiom schema of specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification).

Even if you aren't going to dive deep into set theory as a mathematician, you need to be aware of the preceding two requirements, or you will find yourself incorrectly talking about a set of all sets (or a set of all groups, or vector spaces) and will become ensnared by various paradoxes, e.g., [Russell's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_paradox).

#### Concrete example

In your case, the statement "$B$ is an open Ball in $X$" is one that can be translated (rather painfully) into the formal language of set theory, i.e., ***roughly*** along the lines of $$B\subseteq X\wedge\exists r{\in}ℝ^+\ \exists x{\in}X\ \forall y{\in}X\ ( \ y\in B\iff  d(x,y)<r \ )$$

To show the set of open balls in $X$ exists, call the above formula $\phi(B)$, then
the axiom schema of specification says that $$\{B\in \mathcal P(X)\mid \phi(B)\}$$
is a well-defined set.

Comment: This is a great answer. I'll just add that this whole idea is what people mean by slogans like "There is no set of all sets satisfying a property, but there is a set of all *subsets* satisfying a property." (e.g. similarly there is no set of all fields, but there is a set of all subfields of $\mathbb{C}$)

Comment: Just writing $\exists r > 0 \ \exists x \in X$ makes it a lot more readable than $\exists r \ \exists x ( r > 0) \land (x \in X)$

Comment: @JannikPitt good point, fixed it, thanks.

Comment: @JannikPitt: In general, there is a disappointingly poor pedagogy regarding FOL, in which one-sorted FOL with unrestrictive quantification is taught to students instead of many-sorted FOL with restricted quantification. The argument that the former is sufficient is of course (as you know) invalid since the purpose is to teach and not to minimize the logical language. Related to that issue, numerous teachers insist that it is impossible to teach full FOL to students because it is too symbolic, but well, this (failure to pick the best syntax) is just one of the many reasons it's hard to learn!

Comment: @MW: I have edited the syntax of your FOL statement to make it more precise and systematic and hence pedagogically better in my opinion; feel free to revert if you dislike it!

Comment: @user21820 no I like your change a lot, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

> From my understanding of sets, a set is well-defined in Naive set theory if we can check whether an element is in it or not.

Depending on exactly what you mean by "check," adopting this attitude takes you pretty quickly into [constructivism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructivism_(philosophy_of_mathematics)) and related topics. You actually run into difficulties much earlier though. Before we can talk about metric spaces we have to define $\mathbb{R}$, and in order to define $\mathbb{R}$ we have to construct, depending on your taste, either the set of Cauchy sequences of elements of $\mathbb{Q}$ or the set of Dedekind cuts of elements of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Now, how sure are you that these are sets? Can you check whether a sequence is a Cauchy sequence, or whether a partition of $\mathbb{Q}$ is a Dedekind cut?

(For an example of the sort of thing that can go wrong, one way to define a Cauchy sequence of rationals is that it is a sequence $x_k \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that for every positive integer $\ell$ we can find another positive integer $N(\ell)$ such that, if $n, m \ge N(\ell)$, then $|x_n - x_m| \le \frac{1}{\ell}$. To actually "check" this condition you might decide that you need to actually find all of these positive integers $N(\ell)$. But it could be the case that the sequence $x_n$ converges so slowly that the function $\ell \mapsto N(\ell)$ could grow too fast to be computable, or worse, could grow so fast that you can't prove that it's well-defined in, say, ZFC.)

This is a genuinely nontrivial issue in [constructive analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_analysis) and one is led to doing things like modifying the definition of a Cauchy sequence to include an explicit [modulus of convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_sequence#Modulus_of_Cauchy_convergence). It can also happen that constructively Cauchy sequences and Dedekind cuts define two non-isomorphic versions of the real numbers; see e.g. the nLab article on [Cauchy reals](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Cauchy+real+number) for a discussion of this.

Comment: Thank you! I do have realized that my attitude is sometimes unnecessarily clumsy. Just curious, usually when you encounter a set, how do you check whether it's well-defined or not?

Comment: @Coco: you just develop a sense over time of which set-theoretic constructions are valid. It can help to study a little formal set theory but it's not really necessary, you can just keep learning a bunch of mathematics to see what sorts of things people do. You can take products, unions, disjoint unions, the power set, and take the subset of a set described by a property. That should cover a lot already.

Answer (score 3):

We start with a set $X$. By the axiom of the power set in ZFC we get that the set of subsets of $X$ exists. Since each open ball around an element of $X$ is a subset of $X$, the set of open balls in $X$ is a subset of the power set.

Therefore, the set of open balls exists.